# How to split a value in a row into separate columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with rows like:

```
text1   text2    text3     text4
```

The result that I want is to separate them into different columns, like this:

| text1 | text2 | text3 | text1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

The problem is that in a row there may me multiple empty spaces.

How can I get this result in Postgresql?

Comment: Are there always 4 substrings in your string? Are there an arbitrary number of spaces between the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/r8hWMNQY)):

```
SELECT 
  a[1] AS field1, a[2] AS f2, a[3] AS f3, a[4] AS f4
FROM 
(
  SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY('text1       text2    text3     text4', '[ ]+')
) AS split(a);
```

Result:

```
field1  f2      f3      f4
text1   text2   text3   text4
```

Explanation of regexp (i.e. separator):

`[ ]+` - a space 1 or more times, i.e. an arbitrary number of spaces.